# MySQL replication with NULL-able column on Master and NOT NULL on Slave

Tags: mysql, replication, sql-mode

I got Master table with such column defined: `INT DEFAULT NULL;` and the Slave having that column defined as `NOT NULL;`. InnoDB engine.

SQL mode on both servers is:`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

The question is: why INSERT to that column `NULL` value on Master successfully replicated on Slave (inserting "0" value)? (I expect it to fail).

I even took that statement and run it on Slave and it gave the expected error "column col cannot be null". But the same statement succeeds when replicating...

Hope to get the answer :)
P.S. sorry for my English.

Comment: I can have different data types, on Master and Slave, it's not the problem :)
The problem is why is does not work as expected). Probably the answer is in the binlog, that can have different sql_mode.

Comment: i did more research on this topic it indeed same you can have different datatypes in **some cases**.. it's in the manual in section `17.4.1.9.2 Replication of Columns Having Different Data Types` [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html) they are not talking with differences between `NULL` or `NOT NULL` like you are using tho.

Comment: It is not related to my question...

Comment: it is more or less related to your question.. the manual does not confirm if you can have NULL vs NOT NULL differences in tables structures in master and slave configuration without problems..

Comment: If you put it that way then maybe you're right :)

Comment: Check if you are having Statement based Replication or Row based replication. If it is Row based, then its behaviour is different, as it does not fire queries on slave to insert/update/delete the data.